# Is there a homomorphism from the general linear group of order n to the real numbers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

I know that some subgroups of the General Linear group of order to are Isomorphic to some subgroups of $Z_n$ and I wondered if this can be generalized. I stated homomorphism because I am trying to make the question as general as possible but if it turns out that there is an isomorphism as well that would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\det: GL(n,\mathbb R) \to \mathbb R^\times$ is a (surjective) homomorphism.

Comment: Note: every homomorphism from $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ to an abelian group factors through the determinant map, so this is not just an example, it's _the_ example.

Comment: @Slade that is very interesting!!! Why the restriction of "abelian group" though? Aren't most General Linear Groups non-abelian?

Comment: @MathMan But $(\mathbb{R},+)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^\times,\cdot)$ are both abelian, and these are the groups you asked about.  Any group homomorphism $G\to H$ factors through the [abelianization](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Abelianization.html) $G\to G_{ab}$, and in this case the abelianization is just the determinant map.  In general, there are lots of homomorphisms $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ to non-abelian groups (like the identity map to itself!), but very few to abelian ones.